# Presto Integration with Metabase

Tags: presto, metabase

Metabase 0.24 has a welcome presto integration. I'm currently testing it. However I see that it requires Database name, username and password fields to connect.

My understanding is that presto setups comprise of multiple databases possibly of different types. I have several mysql databases in my Presto catalog.

What's supposed to go into these fields? I'm confused how the integration is supposed to work

Answer (score 1):

At least with the current Metabase Presto driver, I found that:

1. You need to activate authentication (for example password file), which also means activating HTTPS. The later is not trivial with a self-signed certification, by the way. In any case, once activated, you can create a user and password that you'll use in Metabase
2. For a catalog, just enter one of your catalogs. It'll be your main catalog (which will save you some typing), but you can access all catalogs and perform cross-catalog queries by entering the tables' full names

Answer (score 0):

Metabase connects to one catalog of Presto at a time.
For each catalog that you have defined, if it has user authentication, you need to enter the details. If the catalog doesn't have any authentication, leave the username and password fields blank.